# Getting Error when creating custom names in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I have been trying to execute the following query:-

```
select * from pc.A,rpc.B from pparam pc, rparam rpc where pc.A=rpc.B and rpc.C=3945;
```

But I am getting the following error:-

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 70 Column: 42
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: You have given two from statements . 
select * **from** pc.A,rpc.B **from** pparam pc, rparam rpc where pc.A=rpc.B and rpc.C=3945;

Comment: @NzGuy : I think you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @A Prad : Please accept the answer if this solves your error.

Answer (score 1):

You have given two **from** statements .

> select * **from** pc.A,rpc.B **from** pparam pc, rparam rpc where
>   pc.A=rpc.B and rpc.C=3945;